# Silverlight 5 Final Release Date

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-5.0

Does anyone know anything of when the final version of Silverlight is going to be released?
Actually, I've based one of my projects on Silverlight 5 and It has to be released within the next month.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: May I know what you have done with your project please. I am about to start a project but I do face the prospect of having to release a working version in a month.

Comment: Its getting close to the end of the year :(

Comment: The only one thing left is to wait until the Development Tools are released.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

SL 5 was relased on 12/9

http://silverlight.net

**11/30 edit**
Looks like a delay.  It sounded like RTW was eminent, so hopefully it's not much longer.
http://www.zdnet.com/blog/microsoft/microsoft-no-silverlight-5-release-in-november/11299

**11/2 edit:**
Scott Guthrie stated that Silverlight 5 is coming out this month at his 9th Unplugged Q&A last week.

There is a recap by an attendee in the comment section:
http://www.linkedin.com/groups/What-did-you-hear-Scott-43315.S.77526823

The audio archive:
http://www.lidnug.org/Files/Recordings/Oct%2026,%202011%20%20-%20LIDNUG%20%20Scott%20Guthrie%20Unplugged.zip

http://www.lidnug.org/archives.aspx

**Original:**
Getting Closer, Silverlight 5 RC was released yesterday.  Unfortunately, it still does not have a "Go Live" license.

http://www.silverlight.net/download

http://10rem.net/blog/2011/09/01/silverlight-5-rc-now-available

Answer (score 4):

The final release is due to be shipped towards the year end of 2011.

Comment: Do the applications built upon beta version expire? If yes, When?

Comment: For that there is something called Go Live license. So don't worry. They will NOT Expire ;)

Comment: But There is no Go-Live license for Silverlight 5 beta, Am I right?

Comment: Production ready "end user" runtime is not available by know but in the upcoming months it will be. I'm giving you this advice considering that you already based your project on silverlight 5. If there's a big hurry to release now. Or no need to use S5 or there's no big code base then maybe is better to get S4 while they release it.

Answer (score 1):

It was released on Friday 9 December 2011.